# ruby file lock with nfs to run single instance of the script

Tags: ruby

I have implemented file lock mechanism to avoid running multiple process with the same script name and below the method which I used,

```
def main()
 # stufss
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  if File.new(__FILE__).flock(File::LOCK_NB | File::LOCK_EX)
    main
  end
end

__END__
```

Its working fine when I have placed the scripts on local disk, but its not working when the file is located on NFS mounted file system and getting below error,

```
test.rb:64:in `flock': No locks available - test.rb (Errno::ENOLCK)
        from test.rb:64
```

Is it not possible to make this work with the same mechanism?

Note : Am using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Just a note: Ruby 1.8 is pretty old and unsupported for almost four years already (subsequent versions are available for more that six years). I advise to update your environment asap with a high priority. Working with such an old version might be a security issue - at least it makes your job much harder, because current blog post and current gem versions will not be compatible with your old software stack. I suggest to upgrade to at least Ruby 2.2.x, since it is [active supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) at the moment.

Comment: @spickermann I agree completely. Due to compatibility with RHEL5 and 6 I want to stick with this version for now. Yes we are already inprocess of preparing plan to use latest version of Ruby. But am looking if any solution available for now.

Comment: RHEL5 will be unsupported end of month, RHEL6 is not fully supported anymore and RHEL7 is available for almost 3 years. I would advise to update your whole environment.

Comment: I have very huge environment around 50000+ servers combination of RHEL5, 6, and 7, so will take more time for this. Am looking for temporary solution.

Comment: Not sure on what it might mean, but in the doco is the note :- Not available on all platforms. ... Now this could mean that NFS is an unsupported platform??